# Swal alerts not returning value's in netsuite client script in saverecord function of suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, sweetalert, clientscript

The code below is a saverecord function in netsuite which needs to get OK or CANCEL button having true or false value to submit the suitelet.

```
function saveRecord()
{
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: message,
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    },
    function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to `return` a value from your `saveRecord` function.

While I haven't used `swal` specifically, my guess would be that the callback method is invoked asynchronously. You'll have a tough time getting an async dialog to work in conjunction with `saveRecord`.

Comment: can using promises with sweetalerts help? any idea how can we achieve it

Comment: No, promises are the problem, or would behave the same way. They're asynchronous and don't halt execution of the main thread (i.e. the `saveRecord` function).